# How to use for with a function in a django template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am using this function to tokenize sentences in my blog posts:

```
def sentence_tokenize(string):
    sents2 = sent_tokenize(string)
    return sents2
```

In my html template when i am using this line of code:

```
 {% sentence_tokenize post.text %}
```

It successfully sent the post text to the function and return a list of all sentence.

I need to use for loop to get each sentence in seperate line, but it gives an error, here is my code:

```
{% for sentence in sentence_tokenize post.text %}
    {{ sentence }}
{% endfor %}
```

And here is the error:

> TemplateSyntaxError at /post/1/ 'for' statements should use the format
>   'for x in y': for sentence in sentence_tokenize post.text

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by assigning the result of sentence_tokenize to a variable using 'as' like so:

```
{% sentence_tokenize post.text as sentences %}
```

And then iterate over sentences like so:

```
{% for sentence in sentences %}
    {{ sentence }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks. i was searching for variable assement but i did know that is with using just as. it works.